# An application of Uniform Boundedness Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, compactness

I did this problem before

"Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and assume that $C(X)$ is equipped with a norm $||.||$ with which this is a Banach space. For each $x\in X$, define $\lambda_x:C(X)\to \mathbb{R}, f \mapsto f(x)$. Prove that $\sup_x ||\lambda_x||$ is bounded."

What I did: Fix $f\in C(X)$. Then we observe that $\sup_x |\lambda_x(f)|=\sup_x |f(x)|=||f||_{\infty}<\infty$. Hence by the Uniform Boundedness Principle, we deduce  $\sup_x ||\lambda_x||$ is bounded.

This answer was marked correct. But now I read this, why is $||f||_{\infty}<\infty$?

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Because $f \in C(X)$

Comment: $f$ is a continuous function on a compact set, therefore it is bounded. That is why $\|f\|_{\infty} < \infty$

Comment: Oh I missed the compact hypothesis. I was thinking a continuous function can have infinite norm. THank you.

Comment: BTW: Your proof shows directly that $\sup_x \| \lambda_x \| \leq 1 < \infty$. There is no need to invoke the uniform boundedness principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every continuous function from a compact space into $\Bbb R$ is bounded.